# Selenium Error Website Access Denied Webdriver WebdriverWait

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, webdriver, webdriverwait

I get this weird access denied message when I try to login to the "offspring.co.uk" website. This denial message pops up right after clicking the login button. I heard something about the Akamai Bot-Protection on this website. Maybe this protection detects my automation. Does anyone know how to prevent this website access denial?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time



def call_Website():
    # configurations
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
    profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0")

    firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

    # start webdriver etc
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, desired_capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser,20)
    action = ActionChains(browser)


    ###########checkig if proxy works, old snippet
    try:
        browser.get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
    except:
        browser.close()
        print("proxy was not working")
    ##############################################

    time.sleep(2)

    browser.get('https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/secured/content/login')
    time.sleep(2)

    # accept cookie
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()

    time.sleep(1)

    #choose currency
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li.EUR:nth-child(2)").click()

    #fills out username
    username_form = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#user')
    action.move_to_element(username_form).pause(1).click().pause(0.5).send_keys('username')

    #fills out password
    password_form = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#loginpassword')
    action.pause(2).move_to_element(password_form).pause(1).click().pause(0.5).send_keys('password')

    #clicks on login
    Login_Btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#loginButton')))
    action.move_to_element(Login_Btn).pause(1).click().perform()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    call_Website()
```

And here is the "Access Denied"-Page.
[image]

Comment: Can you tell at which stage you are getting the access denied message?

Comment: May be you should give it a try with proxy.

Comment: @KamaleshS this message pops up after I click on the login-Button. So when I type in the username, password and right after clicking "Login".

Comment: @cruisepandey I already tried it with freeproxys but they straight get detected and I get redirected to another site with another error message.

Comment: @domiTHI free proxies have very low success rate and rarely work.

Comment: @KamaleshS yes, recently I've heard of this. But in the programming snippet above I haven't used any proxies. the commented part in the code where proxies are named is just old code which I forgot to remove.